# how to expire fcm push notifications or set lifetime?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My application sending push notifications from the server to several user devices. Notification will valid for a certain time period in my app scenario. currently, all notifications go through my app, but I don't send this at all after given expiration time.
Code to send on a user.

```
   {
      "to":"REGISTRATION_ID",  // "to" replaces "registration_ids"
     "notification": {
        "title": "Portugal vs. Denmark”,
        "body”: "5 to 1”
      },
      "time_to_live":"600"
}
```

Note: "time_to_live" attribute not works.

Comment: you can add a custom field to the notification, and check on the users' devices if it has already expired. If it has - then just don't show notification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the following as per this documentation: [Setting the lifespan of a message.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ttl)

```
"android": {
  "ttl":"600s"
}
```

instead of

```
"time_to_live":"600"
```

Comment: Does this still work??

Answer (score 2):

You should set it as numeric:

```
"time_to_live": 600
```